# Как найти в файле строки по шаблону и занести их в массив?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Как записать в массив строки, найденные в файле по шаблону с помощью  grep? Должен быть скрипт на bash. Чтобы можно было обращаться к конкретной строке по индексу.

Comment: По-моему, вам для такого *AWK* подойдёт лучше, чем сочетание *Bash* и *grep.*

Comment: grep 'шаблон' имяфайла > результирующий_файл

Comment: `a=( $(grep "Шаблонк" /источник) )` Но массив сломается как только в выводе появятся пробелы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно наполнять массив:

```bsh
arr=()
while read s; do
    arr+=( "$s" )
done < <(grep pattern /path/to/file)
```

Основной трюк здесь — перенаправление ввода через *подстановку процесса*, вместо типовой трубы (`grep pattern /path/to/file | while read ...`) т.к. в таком случае `bash` создал бы *подоболочку* (*subshell*) для `while` и все изменения бы пропали, подробности по этому трюку смотри в [BashFaq/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
#Если нужно что бы массив начинался с 1 и соответствовал номеру выбранной строки, расскоментировать строки ниже
#unset mass
#mass[0]="empty"

#Меняем символ разделителя
IFS=$'\n'
#Выбираем данные в массив, символ + стоит указать при начале нумерации с 1, а не 0.
mass+=( `grep Pattern /file` )
#Возвращаем разделитель по умолчанию
unset IFS

#Возвращаем первую строку
echo ${mass[0]}, где 0 - индекс массива
```